# Why didn’t the USA government ask USA companies to take action against India’s neutral stance on the Russo-Ukrainian War?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, india

The Russo-Ukrainian War is an ongoing conflict that began in 2014. India appears to have changed its stance on the war. According to Foreign Minister S. Jaishankar’s statement in the Upper House of Parliament on March 24, 2022, India has dropped its insistence on taking into account the “legitimate security concerns of all countries” (a pro-Russian point) . India remains committed to principles of sovereignty and territorial integrity but won’t be a camp follower.

India’s response to the Russian invasion of Ukraine has been distinctive among the major democracies and among U.S. strategic partners. Despite its discomfort with Moscow’s war, New Delhi has adopted a studied public neutrality toward Russia. It has abstained from successive votes in the UN Security Council, General Assembly, and Human Rights Council condemning Russia’s aggression against Ukraine. The Biden administration is trying to urge India to take a “clear position” on the Russia-Ukraine crisis.

Comment: see also https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75134/what-is-the-political-justification-by-china-and-india-for-not-participating-in

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica My question related to US govt not about political justification of INDIA.

Comment: You have already asked this question and it was deleted, so why asking again? https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78786/why-didn-t-usa-companies-take-action-against-india-s-neutral-stance-on-the-russo

Comment: @convert I asked in wrong way so I modified and posting again.

Comment: Can you include sources for your claim that "India appears to have changed its stance"?

Comment: If they wanted to take action against India wouldn't they do it through sanctions?

Comment: There are a lot of countries that are not 100% supporting the USA - many outside Europe and the white Commonwealth have abstained on some votes. Do you think the US should take action against all of them, or is there a reason to single out India?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is questionable whether USA *companies* realistically take action against a *sovereign country* (India).

This is unlikely to yield change in policy but may easily cause execs of said companies' branches to be jailed in India and the companies kicked out of domestic Indian market. Giving way to China-affiliated ones or even Europeans/British to take their place.

In many ways it is akin to the proposals that ISPs should judge their users' internet use patterns and e.g. punish online piracy. Sounds good to somebody else while ISPs will spend their own money to fire/lose their own customers, get blamed for that and get nothing in return. These companies are not in the business of influencing other countries' stances. In other words, play stupid games, win stupid prizes.

Comment: The question isn't talking about US companies taking unilateral actions not to do business with indian companies but the US government forcing them not to. The US government has threatened many countries with similar sanctions if they support Russia. Question is why have they not done so with India.

Comment: Did they have much success with said threatening? I gather that USA usually has to yield some carrot since the stick is unlikely to work - the USA wants to get its policy across, not sanction half of the world.